# Facebook App with .link domain

Tags: facebook, dns

We have a website: http://onice.link

I want to create a Facebook App to support Facebook Login function.

But in Settings tab, I got this error when I tried to enter onice.link for App Domains:
 **This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: onice.link**

Does not Facebook work with .link domains yet?

Comment: Did you fill out any of the fields mentioned in the message?

Comment: That should definitely work. Echoing @CBroe's comment - you can't just fill out the domain. You need to provide one of those other URL's as well.